# Silverlight site not loading completely

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, silverlight, browser

There is one site called http://hattrick.cognizant.com which is made up of a Silverlight application. This site is opening in all other systems except mine.

I am getting the following exception:

```
Uncaught Error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
   at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)
   at System.Convert.ToDateTime(String value, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToDateTime(IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ToDateTime(Object value)
   at Hattrick.ViewModel.ScoreBoardViewModel.LoadMatchDetails(Object parameter)
   at Hattrick.ViewModel.DelegateCommand.Execute(Object parameter)
   at System.Windows.Interactivity.InvokeCommandAction.Invoke(Object parameter)
   at System.Windows.Interactivity.TriggerBase.InvokeActions(Object parameter)
   at System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTriggerBase.OnEvent(EventArgs eventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTriggerBase.OnEventImpl(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.InvokeSelectionChanged(List`1 unselectedItems, List`1 selectedItems)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectionChanger.End()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectionChanger.SelectJustThisItem(Int32 oldIndex, Int32 newIndex)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.OnSelectedValuePropertyChanged(Object value)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.OnSelectedValuePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.RaisePropertyChangeNotifications(DependencyProperty dp, Object oldValue, Object newValue)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, ValueOperation operation)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.RefreshExpression(DependencyProperty dp)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.SendDataToTarget()
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.SourcePropertyChanged(PropertyPathListener sender, PropertyPathChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.PropertyPathListener.ReconnectPath()
   at System.Windows.PropertyPathListener.RaisePropertyPathStepChanged(PropertyPathStep source)
   at System.Windows.PropertyAccessPathStep.RaisePropertyPathStepChanged(PropertyListener source)
   at System.Windows.CLRPropertyListener.SourcePropertyChanged(Object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Data.WeakPropertyChangedListener.PropertyChangedCallback(Object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at Hattrick.ViewModel.ScoreBoardViewModel.RaisedPropertyChanged(String property)
   at Hattrick.ViewModel.ScoreBoardViewModel.hattrickClient_GetMatchDatesCompleted(Object sender, GetMatchDatesCompletedEventArgs e)
   at Hattrick.HattrickService.HattrickServiceClient.OnGetMatchDatesCompleted(Object state)
```

I did not make this site. Is there any problem with my system configuration?

My Configuration

```
 OS         : Windows 7
 Silverlight: Version 5 latest 64bit
 Browser    : Chrome (Not working in any browser)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer OS Language is in English(India) changed to English(United States) hence the exception is raised regarding datetime format

Answer (score 0):

If site is opened normally on all systems you know except yours and error message is following:

Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Most likely I think it could be difference in your local cultural settings related to date and time. Probably developers do not excpet date time string with format you have, because you have other or specifical cultural settings

Comment: in control panel, try to find somethink like "region and language" and there change your settings to English US (en-US)